# Boxstarter to apply all patches to clean install of Win8.1 - how?

Tags: windows-8.1

Starting point: Plain install of Win 8.1

Is there an existing package or set of steps to use boxstarter to get the OS completely up to date (with a single command)?

(Rather than let Windows take 3+ hours and 3+ reboots to get itself all patched up.)

Answer (score 1):

Boxstarter can do this but it will stil take a while. However, I prefer to let boxstarter do this because you can see the progress as each update is downloaded and installed. Also, you are not prohibited from working while the updates are taking place.

The easiest way to do this from a clean pc is to open this url from internet explorer: http://boxstarter.org/package/Boxstarter.WindowsUpdate

This will install boxtarter in a temporary location and run the WindowsUpdate package. You will be prompted for a password which will be used to perform any needed reboots.

You can also download and install the Boxstarter modules from chocolatey:

```
choco install Boxstarter -y
```

Or you can download them from http://boxstarter.org. Once installed the boxstarter commands can be run from the command line and you can invoke updates by running:

```
$c = Get-Credential
Install-BoxstarterPackage -PackageName Boxstarter.WindowsUpdate -Credential $c
```

Finally, you can include the installation of windows update in any boxstarter package you create by including this command in the package:

```
Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptEula
```

The AcceptEula switch helps to avoid prompts from some of the few updates that may require the acceptance of a eula.